# Using each in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am starting to learn ruby and am trying to figure out a way to if i have an array of 16 numbers, to print those numbers 4 at a time using only the each method. I can easily do this with a loop but i am lacking full understanding of the each method in Ruby so this gives me some trouble.

I have the following:

```
x=[*1..16]
index=0
x.each do |element|
  puts element[index]
  index=index+3
end
```

Now obviously this is completely wrong and i know that but i wanted to put something on here. A little advice would be great.

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean 4 at a time?  each does exactly what it sounds like... iterates through your array for each element. so it wouldn't make sense to use each if you want to print 4 elements of your array at a time.

Comment: I understand that each_slice would be the method to use for this problem but I am working out the exercises in a book I am using for self-study and the problem is to do it using just each and then use each_slice. I am having trouble doing it with the each method only.

Comment: It seems that the issue is that the each method only looks at one element of the array at a time. So if I want to print 4 elements on one line, then skip to the next line and print the next 4 elements, and so on, this becomes a bit of a problem......still not sure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
a = (1..16)
a.each_slice(4) { |s| p s[3] }
```

EDIT: If you want print 4 elements on one line, then skip to the next line and print the next 4 elements, etc

```
a = (1..16)
a.each_slice(4) { |s| puts s.join(' ') }
```

Or using each only

```
a = (1..16)
a.each { |i| print i.to_s + ' '; print "\n" if i % 4 == 0 }
```

Comment: Can this be done using only the each method and not the each_slice method?

Answer (score 2):

Try `each_slice` http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice.

Using that would look something like

```
(1..16).each_slice(4) do |x|
  puts x.inspect
end
```

Comment: But how to do it only using the each method?

Comment: As far as I know, what you are describing is impossible with only `each` which only knows about the current element and nothing else. You could alternatively use `each_with_index` and do something every 4 iterations, but the important thing is that `each` is fundamentally different from a for loop. `each` gives you a single element from a collection to work with at a time and no other information.